# USB to RS-232 Converter Power Option

Tags: usb, serial-port

I have an device that is interfaced with RS-232 that requires power on Pin 6 at 5V and Pin 5 as ground to power the device.

Is it possible to do this with an USB to RS-232 Converter?

If not, what are the other options I have that don't require being an master in electronics, maybe something that's pre-built?

Comment: This should be moved to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You could always go with an [Arduino](http://arduino.cc) and wire up a serial port to the outputs where you could easily send a 5V signal and hook to ground.

Comment: I second the Arduino. We use it at work for remote data logging to our mysql DB.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do with the RS-232 device? Hook it up via USB to a computer? Simply power it without hooking anything up?

Arduino or other prototyping board would work, as would hacking the RS-232/USB adapter.

If you simply need power, you can hack up a wall wart, but be sure to check the output voltage...many of them are not regulated well and will output a significantly higher voltage than the label says if there is not much of a load on them.

Comment: Thanks,I have one of these laying around : http://www.amazon.com/Power-Line-0900-74-Universal-Adapter/dp/B000QDZ4CU Going to test it out at 4.5V I only need .15a

Answer (score 1):

If your device has low power consumption and you can open your USB to RS-232 converter, then you can connect the +5V and GND that from the USB to them.